# A copy constructor call

Tags: c++

I have declared a Point class like this :

```
class Point{
      private :  
      int a,b;  
      public :       
      Point(Point const &p) {
      a = p.a + 1;
      b = 0;
      }
      Point(){a=2; b=3;}
      int getX(){return a;}
      int getY(){return b;}
      };
 int main(){
   Point p1,p2;
   p2=p1;
   cout << p2.getX(); // 2
   cout << p2.getY(); // 3
  }
```

Why the copy constructor is not called ? as it's called here :

```
 int main(){
   Point p1;
   Point p2=p1;
   cout << p2.getX(); // 3
   cout << p2.getY(); // 0
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is copy construction

```
Point p2=p1;  // p2 is constructed here.
              // This is shorthand for Point p2(p1);
```

This is assignment

```
p2=p1;  // p2 already exists (it was created on the previous line).
```

The assignment operator is defined with:

```
// If you don't define this the compiler will generate one for you.
Point& operator=(Point const& rhs)
{
     // Copy for rhs into this.
     return *this;
}


// The compiler generated one looks like this:
Point& operator=(Point const& rhs)
{
     a = rhs.a;
     b = rhs.b;
     return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first program

```
 int main(){
   Point p1,p2;
   p2=p1;
   ^^^^^
```

there is called the copy assignment operator created by the compiler implicitly.
In this program object `p2` was already created using the default constructor

```
   Point p1,p2;
```

In tfhe second program

```
 int main(){
   Point p1;
   Point p2=p1;
   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

there is indeed called the copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Point p1,p2;
 p2=p1;
```

p2 is already constructed so the second statement invokes the assignment operator

Point p1;
Point p2=p1;

Here p2 is copy-constructed since it had not been constructed before.

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
  A() { std::cout << "Ctor called\n"; }
  A(const A&) { std::cout << "Copy Ctor called\n"; }
  A& operator=(const A&) { std::cout << "Assignment operator called\n"; return *this;}

};

int main() {
  A a,b;
  b = a;
  A c;
  A d = c;
}
```

the output of which is enlightening:

```
Argento:Desktop marinos$ clang++ test.cpp -o test
Argento:Desktop marinos$ ./test
Ctor called
Ctor called
Assignment operator called
Ctor called
Copy Ctor called
```